# Symbol class to document class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I have this code in my document class:

```
package  {

    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var mainMenu = new MainMenu();


        public function Main() {
            // constructor code
            startGame();
        }

        public function startGame(){
            mainMenu.x = stage.stageWidth/2
            addChild(mainMenu);     
        }

        public function initGame(event){
            //Adding player with and stuff
        }
}

}
```

And this in my MainMenu class:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class MainMenu extends MovieClip {

        private var logo = new Logo();      

        public function MainMenu() {
            // constructor code
            logo.x = - logo.width/2;
            logo.y = 50;
            logo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, initGame);
            addChild(logo);
            }
    }

}
```

I get this message when i try to test the game; 1120: Access of undefined property initGame.
Why can't the mainMenu.as access the public function initGame?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You require a reference to the `Main` object inside `MainMenu`. You can pass it through the constructor:

```
mainMenu = new MainMenu(this);
```

And inside `MainMenu` you can now register an event to a method inside `Main`.

```
public function MainMenu(main:Main) {
    logo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, main.initGame);
    //...
}
```

Comment: When i do so, i get this error: 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1. 
The error is pointed towards 
public var mainMenu = new MainMenu();

Comment: @scou make sure the arguments are correct for your callback: `initGame(event:MouseEvent):void`